# Removing users from chat (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, hashtable

I have developed a client/server chat application using Java and I wish to know how can I remove a user from an array. When a specific client log-in the username is saved in username array and client ID in client array. To allow the server to accept multiple clients, I am using threads. Now can anyone guide me on how to remove a user from the array and also close the connection for that user.

Adding a new client and saving the ID in client array

```
public class AddClient implements Runnable {

    Thread t;

    AddClient(String tot) {
        t = new Thread(this, tot);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                try {
                    waitClient();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < client.length; i++) {
                    if (client[i] == 0) {
                        client[i] = i + 1;
                        id = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //set stream to send and receive data
                out[client[id]] = new ObjectOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream());
                out[client[id]].flush();
                in[client[id]] = new ObjectInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
```

The username is saved in the username array

```
username[client[id]] = cm.sender; //Add user in username[] array
```

Removing user

```
public synchronized void removeUser(int number) {
    int position = number;
    System.out.println("Server removing user " + username[number] + "which is client " + number);

    for (int i = 0; i <= client.length; i++) {
        if (position == client[i]) {
            System.out.println("User to be remove found");
            try {
                client[i + 1] = client[i];
                in[position].close();
                out[position].close();
                username[position] = null;
                position = position - 1;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use HashTable to add and remove the client

```
public class ChatServerProtocol {
private String nick;
private AddClient a;

private Hashtable<String, AddClient> nicks = new Hashtable<String, AddClient>();


private boolean add_nick(String nick, AddClient a) {
    if (nicks.containsKey(nick)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        nicks.put(nick, a);
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean remove_nick(String nick, AddClient a) {
    if (!(nicks.containsKey(nick))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        nicks.remove(nick);
        return true;
    }
}

public ChatServerProtocol(AddClient a) throws IOException {
    nick = null;
    a = a;
}
```

But now how do I call the method add_nick. Whenever a client log-in the username is sent to the server and the server reads it as cm.sender. I also need to include the thread variable. So how to add the username so that later i can remove it.

```
  ChatServerProtocol.add_nick(cm.sender);
```

Comment: You should indicate the line where exception is thrown in the code in the question.

Comment: Also, don't use Java array for a purpose like this... In this case, you should use a `Map`. Also, when ever you feel like using an array, you should almost always use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I was thinking whether if I send the client ID and username details to my database and whenever they logout I just remove their details using the SQL Query. Would it be a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

No, saving in database won't be a good idea.. Remember you are saving details only for the length of the session and basic concept of database is to use it after the session. What happens if your session gets interruped because of network issues etc?

Just use Map instead of plain arrays, using key as client ID and value as username.. removing username will be a plain call such as map.remove(clientID);

**EDIT AS YOU ASKED:** Note that this code is not complete and only as much as you gave..

public class AddClient implements Runnable {
    Thread t;

```
private Map<int, String> users = new HashMap <int, String>();

AddClient(String tot) {
    t = new Thread(this, tot);
    t.start();
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            try {
                waitClient();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

            int clientId = users.size() + 1;
            users.put(clientId, cm.sender);


            //set stream to send and receive data
            out[clientId] = new ObjectOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream());
            out[clientId].flush();
            in[clientId] = new ObjectInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
```

**REMOVE USER METHOD**

public synchronized void removeUser(int number) {

```
            if(users.containsKey(number)) {
               System.out.println("Server removing user " + users.get(number) + "which is client " + number);
               users.remove(number);
            } else {
               System.out.println("User not in session");
            }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question! I am sorry but it's the first time I am using HashTable. So can you help me regarding this matter. Thanks.